# Encoding String content as XML in web service request

Tags: web-services, websphere-7

I am dealing with a problem where I must use a legacy web services client developed from a WSDL that passes in the actual XML request as the value of the only one variable in the request. The web service that I am consuming now has a different WSDL and I am trying to trick my XML parser however it is encoding my actual XML response.

Is there anyway to configure the parser so the request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <request>&lt;elemA&gt;&lt;elemB&gt;abc&lt;/elemB&gt;&lt;/elemA&gt;</request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

is changed into this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <foo>
         <elemA>
            <elemB>abc</elemB>
         </elemA>
      </foo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am using JAX-WS and WebSphere 7.

Thanks in advance.

Pablo

Comment: The original design is worth posting to http://thedailywtf.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with this situation once last year, the solution for me was to wrap the XML that was going inside the soap message inside a CDATA section.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <![CDATA[
          <foo>
             <elemA>
                <elemB>abc</elemB>
             </elemA>
          </foo>
          ]]
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```